# Gradle Can't Download Plugins From HTTPS Through Proxy

Tags: gradle, proxy

I've been trying to get gradle to download a plugin, which is coming from an HTTPS URL, and can't for the life of my figure out what I'm doing wrong.  From what I've read on the internet, this is usually solved by setting a proxy - which I have, and from the debug logs gradle appears to be using it.  I've also tried manually adding the certificates that are listed for all of the URLs in the debug log to my cacerts file to no avail.

The debug log - from the last redirect performed by gradle for the springboot plugin - is shown below:

```
Redirecting to 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.4.3.RELEASE.pom' via {tls}->http://myProxy:2020->https://jcenter.bintray.com:443
can be kept alive indefinitely
Connection released: [id: 204][route: {tls}->http://myProxy:2020->https://plugins.gradle.org:443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
CookieSpec selected: default
Auth cache not set in the context
Connection request: [route: {tls}->http://myProxy:2020->https://jcenter.bintray.com:443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
Connection leased: [id: 206][route: {tls}->http://myProxy:2020->https://jcenter.bintray.com:443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 3 of 20]
Opening connection {tls}->http://myProxy:2020->https://jcenter.bintray.com:443
Connecting to myProxy/myProxyIp:2020
Connection established myIp:64916<->myProxyIp:2020
Tunnel to target created.
Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
Enabled cipher suites:[Removed for readability]
Starting handshake
http-outgoing-206: Shutdown connection
Connection discarded
http-outgoing-206: Close connection
Connection released: [id: 206][route: {tls}->http://myProxy:2020->https://jcenter.bintray.com:443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
Flushing resolved configuration data in Binary store in C:\Temp\gradle7433380394459999850.bin. Wrote root 2.
Timing: Running the build script took 1.082 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'TutorialHelloWorld'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE.
         > Could not parse POM https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.3.RELEASE.pom
            > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:1.4.3.RELEASE.
               > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:1.4.3.RELEASE.
                  > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.4.3.RELEASE.pom'.
                     > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.4.3.RELEASE.pom'.
                        > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 

BUILD FAILED
```

I can download this file through my browser, which also uses the proxy so that should be OK.  This is with Java 1.8.0_71-b15 and gradle 3.4.

I also tried the same command from the same machine on a network with no proxy (and no proxy configured for gradle) and ended up with the same error, so it seems like this is something with my environment rather than the proxy.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: try again with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` so you can see what's going on with the certificate chain. Clearly, something is not matching between what your browser considers a valid cert, and JDK8's trust store.

Answer (score 1):

i have no root, and this helped me

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS+="-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$HOME/jks/cacerts"
keytool -import -alias root_ca -trustcacerts -keystore $HOME/jks/cacerts -file /tmp/root-ca.pem
keytool -import -alias sub_ca -trustcacerts -keystore $HOME/jks/cacerts -file /tmp/sub-ca.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rebooting the machine after my last edit, and now the `gradle build` command seems to be working fine; I'm not sure what the reboot would have changed or if it's going to stay this way, but at least right now it seems to be working.